# remplazo valores anómalos de un dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un **dataFrame** de grandes datos, los cuales deben ser solo *numéricos*, *enteros* o *flotantes*, pero  existe la posibilidad que posean valores que **no** son números, **cadenas** son los más comunes en algunos lugares.

¿Cómo podría encontrar y cambiar las *cadenas* a valores **NaN** de forma eficiente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `df["columna"].apply(lambda x: x if type(x) in [float, int] else "NaN")`

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df["columna"], errors="coerce")`

Comment: mucho mejor la de abulafia

Comment: @Christian Sí, más que nada porque `"NaN"` sigue siendo una cadena, no es `NaN` (para obtener éste debes usar `float("nan")`). Además es más lento el `.apply()`, y además probablemente cambiaría todos los datos por "NaN", pues en pandas las  celdas de una columnas son todas del mismo tipo, por lo que si en alguna celda hay un string, la columna completa contendrá strings

Comment: @abulafia creo que en numpy existía el tipo `NaN` con `numpy.nan`  así que tambien habría optado por eso. Casí siempre uso `apply` y creo que es por eso que primero doy una solución con eso xd.

Comment: muchas  gracias, lastima no pueda darle un me gusta a sus respuesta, trate con el to_numeric de pandas pero lo use mal, y abulafia tiene razón están en formato cadena las columnas que contienen al guion, "-".